# Deprecated HTML important to lower slope of learning curve?

Tags: html, deprecated

I am very well aware of the principles behind deprecating layout HTML like FONT, CENTER, etc., in favor of the more-or-less equivalent CSS.

But, in reading the extensive amount of verbiage on this over the years, I've never read anything about what this does to the *teaching* of HTML, especially to those new to the entire concept of computer languages, markup, and metadata.

I'm thinking of 4th and 5th graders, but there are many older people who fit this profile, too.

Suppose one of these kids wants to build a website with things that kids like, such as colors, font families and sizes, formatting, and so on?

In putting together a course for schoolchildren, I find they want to know about controlling presentation at about lesson 5, just after I've introduced paragraphs. But, this is no time to introduce CSS, as I haven't even gotten to attributes yet. Equal signs, colons, quotes, and brackets are still sea of confusing characters at this point.

Trying to teach:

```
<p style='text-align: center;'>
```

instead of

```
<center>
```

just doesn't work. The students get discouraged and the course grinds to a halt.

Worse, the two aren't equivalent, since the inline styles only apply to one tag, whereas the deprecated tag applies until ended. Introducing DIV to get around this is no real help, as it still suffers from taking the student down a complex path much too early.

OK, so there must be a question in here at some point, right? ;-)

How about this for a some questions:

1. Has anyone actually taught HTML to 4th and 5th graders without using deprecated tags?
2. Is anyone aware of any part of the various HTML standards development that included educational issues? (I'm not talking about education for highly motivated, somewhat technically-inclined adults here. I'm talking about HTML for kids and casual computer users.)
3. Is anyone out there willing to agree with me that teaching deprecated HTML is a way to lower the slope of the learning curve?
4. Reviewing in my mind the various reasons for deprecation, I can't see why, for example, deprecating CENTER is justified. While it has been removed from certain strict HTML standards, there will never be a browser that doesn't handle it. (Other than research tools.) While more powerful constructs exist, none of them are even close to as convenient to code. Thoughts on this issue?

(Please, no responses along the lines of "let beginners use WYSIWYG editors". These kids want to learn HTML, not just post some pretty content. There's a big difference.)

Answer (score 2):

I first have to commend you on a bold mission. My wife is a 5th grade teacher and I have seen worlds of difference in one student's inability to spell their own name vs. some that can do serious math. To teach them html when they haven't even mastered basic spelling is a challenge I would not dare take. But that is not the point...

I am a professional web developer. I have tried to teach people (grown up interns at our firm) basic code before, but limited time prevents me from getting too involved in more technical details. Even they had a hard time "getting it" so to say. So it could be similar to a kind of curriculum. I would say this - for students in 4th or 5th grade only - basic deprecated html 4 is perfectly acceptable to teach. I would boilerplate a basic template because I can't imagine them understanding headers or anything like that.

Why is it acceptable? Because the odds are less than 1% will actually go on to do anything with it. If they do, they are competent enough to understand the progression of code and have little problems adapting to the real world environment. Anyhow, they may end up taking a CS course and figuring out what's happening behind the code. The rest of them will probably dismiss it and never look back.

Good luck. I am curious to see the results of this plan. Make a site and report the progress.

Comment: Thanks, Kai. Regarding a boilertplate template: I never understood why introductory HTML text always start with DOCTYPE, HTML, HEAD, etc. There is no browser on earth that won't take plain text and do something very reasonable with it. I don't introduce <!DOCTYPE html> until maybe 20 lessons in. From that point, all examples are valid HTML. My approach is always to start simply, even if what I'm teaching is somewhat wrong, and then correct later. The ability of the student to learn is my primary concern, not the needs of the browser, the standards bodies, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that while more complicated to start with, the separation of content from style is a key concept for writing real web pages and if learnt early on would give anyone a huge advantage later if they were to continue with their learning rather than use deprecated techniques.

Would doing something using classes to replicate the basic style properties provided by these tags be that hard to teach?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.center {text-align: center;}
.bold   {font-weight: bold;}
.italic {font-style: italic;}
.big {font-size: 18;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="big center bold">
Hello world!
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I guess as it's at such a young age, maybe it would. Although as Kai suggested you will need a boilerplate template to provide them anyway, so setting up a bunch of classes and placing all the formatting for a paragraph in one place (in the class attribute) is in my opinion easier to read and understand than having a whole lot of tags you have to remember to close.

Comment: True. I wondered about even the concept of wrapping a single word in a tag at all, nevermind that the tag has the <> signs surrounding them as well as a closing tag that will have a slash. What about self closing tags like hr? You would be amazed how many 5th graders will tell you 15 - 4 = 17. Or some other equally illogical answer. A tag or class - whichever you choose - will be understood by those who will grasp anything at all. The rest will probably struggle with either.